# Assign buses to routes base on their capacity

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, linear-algebra, calculus

I am facing problem in assigning buses to routes. I have four buses and four routes with their capacities.

Bus capacity is the number of seats in each bus. Route capacity is number of people on each stop of a route. Route is actually a combination of multiple stops.

An example of a single test case is:

```
BUS CAPACITY          ROUTE CAPACITY
BUS 1 44 Seats        Route 1 30 Peoples
BUS 2 63 Seats        Route 2 50 Peoples
BUS 3 14 Seats        Route 3 40 Peoples
BUS 4 17 Seats        Route 4 17 Peoples
```

There is a lot of test cases with multiple combinations for this problem. The numbers of routes and buses are always equal.

I am looking for a algorithm that helps out in solve this problem optimally.

Comment: Your question show Route 1 four times? What cost or merit function do you try to optimize? What have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: i did this by finding closest difference between buses and routes and then assign closest bus to route but it didn't help, need any other solution that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm

or

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

approaches basically you are looking for best match.

In layman's terms what you might want to do is find the best matching route to a bus where best matching is defined as where the bus capacity to route capacity is optimal i.e. busCapacity - routeCapacity is lowest positive number.

Once you find such matches they will be eliminated from the problem world.

Then repeat this for the remaining world.

The end product is that everything is matched.

However prepare of the unexpected:-

You may exhaust all the possible combination and left with smaller capacity and bigger route capacity. In this case you look for difference between  i.e.  routeCapacity - busCapacity to be least as the best match.

This is so that the number of people you gave to let know that they can't be served is minimal.

Comment: when i told about multiple test cases this means the given example can have variety of combination, it didn't mean i have to choose best match from multiple test cases. Your referred algorithm was good for such problem, but on the one i am working on, i have to find best for individual test case, let say for the given one i have to find best match. if you find have any idea for such problem that means a lot me. Sorry for any misguidance.

Comment: I suggest you describe the test case that did not work but more importantly what you tried for solving that. Because in your question you basically asking `I am facing problem in assigning buses to routes` The algorithm I laid out is to precisely solve this problem generically. Most of us are very code oriented so we can help in refining or fixing some code. No worries about misguidance please.

Comment: i haven't write a code for this, because i stuck badly while making logic, what i was trying is actually subtracting capacities and then finding the closest distance so that i can assign buses to routes, but i am not satisfy with this solution, need any other way to do this. I have watched a tutorial of your suggested algorithm in which a tissue problem was solved. Might be you're familiar with that problem, i don't think it can help me out.Actually I am not getting the Euclidean equation with respect to my problem. if you can then set the given data into equation so that i can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually say what optimal means here, and that might change what the best solution is, but I would be inclined to sort the routes and buses and then assign the largest bus to the route with the largest number of people waiting, the next largest bus to the route with the next largest number of people waiting, and so on.

There will be unhappy people here if a route is assigned a bus that doesn't have enough seats for the people on the route, but with this assignment all of the buses with more seats are assigned to routes with even more people waiting, so giving a bigger bus would leave at least as many other people without a seat.

For a more sophisticated way of matching people and buses look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

An example of how the definition of optimal changes things is if you don't care about the number of people annoyed but about the number of routes where people don't get a seat. In this case if you have routes with 2,3,5,9 people waiting and buses to carry 1,2,4,8 people it might make sense to assign them as 2 people-2 seats, 3 people-4 seats, 5 people-8 seats, 9-people-1 seat which leaves 8 people without a seat instead of 4 but all of those 8 people are on just 1 route.